# IAM authority lacks the permission 'clientauthconfig.clients.list' for action AppIdentityClientAuthConfigService-ListClients on resource 'brands/XXX'

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We are currently hosting a Docker container in Google Cloud's Cloud Run.

We're trying to initialize a revision to Cloud Run (Manually and via an authenticated pipeline). It's complaining that it doesn't have access to the resource.

Our team has been struggling over several days to fix the following issue:

```
Error: Revision 'api-XXXXX-grn' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.

Reason:
- Failed to list OAuth clients due to a permission issue.

Details:
- Exception: com.google.apps.framework.auth.IamPermissionDeniedException
- IAM authority lacks the permission 'clientauthconfig.clients.list' for action AppIdentityClientAuthConfigService-ListClients on resource 'brands/XXXXXXXXXXX'.

Security Context:
- User: gaiauser/XXXXXXXXXX
- Credentials: GAIA_MINT
- Peer Protocol: loas
- Peer Version: X
- Security Level: strong_privacy_and_integrity
- Host: XXXXXXXX.prod.google.com
- Role: identity-app-regional
- User: cloud-run-api-server
- Originator: cloud-run-api-server (GAIA ID: XXXXXXXXXXXX)

RPC Exception:
- Title: /ClientAuthConfig.ListClients, PERMISSION_DENIED
- Application Error: google.identity.clientauthconfig.v1/ClientAuthConfig.ListClients
- App Error Code: X
- Start Time (ms): XXXXXXXXXXXX
- Deadline (sec): XX.X
- Server Time (sec): X.XXXXXXXX
- Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
- Server: [XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::]:XXXX

For in-depth troubleshooting, please visit:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting
```

These are the permissions we've set to the user:

[image]

We're trying to run it through the Policy Troubleshooter but haven't found the culprit yet.

The `brands/XXXXXXXXXXX` resource is what's throwing us off.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @Mikkel We contacted Google Cloud customer support

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Cloud Run Service Agent service account has the Cloud Run Service Agent role on your project.

Comment: It has the Service Agent role. Any ideas? We do have a VPC attached to it. Could the VPC be the culprit?